# Transitioning MapServer from 32bit to 64bit: CGI Error

Tags: python, apache, cgi, wms, mapserver

I am moving a mapserver system from 32bit to 64bit Windows (too many frustrations with multiple python installations). There is no straightforward MS4W installation for 64 bit. I am using Apache2.4 and 64bit mapserver from GISInternals. I added the mapser.exe file to the cgi-bin folder of Apache, but I am not sure if there are other changes required to match the MS4W setup. I get the following in the Apache error log when trying to open a page containing a mapfile:

```
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080] Internal Server Error: /mapit/mapYr/luz_mapfile_scen1_yr_160525_070507
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 149, in get_response
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\handlers\\base.py", line 147, in get_response
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]   File "C:/MapItApplication\\web_output\\mapit\\views.py", line 1132, in view_mapYr
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]     wms = WebMapService(mapServerUrl, version='1.1.1')
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\owslib\\wms.py", line 85, in __init__
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]     self._capabilities = reader.read(self.url, timeout=self.timeout)
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]   File "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\owslib\\wms.py", line 700, in read
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]     return etree.fromstring(u.read())
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]   File "C:\\Python27\\Lib\\xml\\etree\\ElementTree.py", line 1300, in XML
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]     parser.feed(text)
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]   File "C:\\Python27\\Lib\\xml\\etree\\ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]     self._raiseerror(v)
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]   File "C:\\Python27\\Lib\\xml\\etree\\ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080]     raise err
[Wed May 25 07:14:18.838731 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080] ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 49
[Wed May 25 07:14:49.944510 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 3432:tid 1080] [client *removed for posting*] End of script output before headers: mapserv.exe
```

http config file (Updated):

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

WSGIScriptAlias /mapit C:/MapItApplication/web_output/apache/mapit_django.wsgi


<Directory "C:/MapItApplication/web_output/apache">
     AllowOverride None
    Options Indexes MultiViews Includes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>

##

Alias /mapimages    "C:/MapItApplication/web_output/images"

<Directory "C:/MapItApplication/web_output/images">
    AllowOverride None
    Options Indexes MultiViews Includes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I am following: http://www.onegeology.org/wmsCookbook/4_4_3.html

**Update:**
The parse error seems to be a misnomer caused by python trying to parse an error page. The error is "End of script output before headers: mapserv.exe"

**Update** - Traceback
[image]

Comment: Are you able to test whether the MapServer implementation is working correctly outside of trying to access it through Django?  Do you get an error  if you make a GetCapabilities request to the mapServerURL directly in a browser.  What about if you make the same request directly in Python using owslib.

Comment: something like: `import owslib.wms as wms` `w = wms.WebMapService(mapServerUrl,version='1.1.1')` `print("Service is: " + w.identification.title)` ...